# Новая почта(Android API)

Tags: android, retrofit

Не получается получить доступ к `API` новой почты.

Использую `Retrofit` для работы с сетью.

Вот таким образом формирую интерфейс:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/v2.0/json")
Call<NovaPochtaSityModel> getSity(@Field("apiKey") String key, @Field("modelName") String modelName, @Field("calledMethod") String calledMethod);
```

Ну и затем обращаюсь к серверу:

```
Call<NovaPochtaSityModel> call = api.getSity("key","InternetDocument","getDocumentList");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<NovaPochtaSityModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NovaPochtaSityModel> call, Response<NovaPochtaSityModel> response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NovaPochtaSityModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Fail");
        }
    });
```

ну и собственно инициализация:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
            .baseUrl("https://api.novaposhta.ua")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
```

В ответ ловлю:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to api.novaposhta.ua/185.128.233.69 (port 8883) after 10000ms
```

Увеличивал время ожидания до 60 секунд, не помогло. Да и данных там не так много чтобы тянуть их дольше минуты

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да ладно! Этим кто-то пользуется!

Comment: А оно и через браузер если заходить по ссылке - через раз отрабатывает, отлупляя ошибкой открытия SSL тунеля

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте подергать `API` через `Postman` это поможет проверить насколько правильно вы указываете ключи, заголовки. Извините, не силен в `android` и `java`, ничего не могу сказать по вашему коду, но вообще ошибка таймаута это скорее серверные проблемы.
Вообще странный порт, вы пробовали менять на `80` или `443`?

Ну Вам же вернуло ошибку. Скорее всего она заключается в том, что вы отправляете данные в url, а надо в body выставить raw и в нем сформировать джисон согласно описанию в доках, добавить хоть какие-нить хеды и отправить это все на `https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json`

Comment: пост мэн тоже ждет 10 секунд и кидает ошибку

Comment: На 80-й порт - ругается сертификат,на 443 та же самая ошибка

Comment: да, это капец, у них чтобы зарегаться надо пол дня убить, смс приходит через пять минут

Comment: @Heaven у меня постмен нормально отработал, с каким методом проблема? Писали в поддержку?

Comment: Sergeevich Добавил скрин под UPD

Comment: @Heaven я отредактировал ответ